# Writing strings to text file android

Tags: android, string, file

I am new to android programming and I am trying to write strings into a text file without overwriting the previous one. It is somehow like a history log of the application. I tried reading online guide but it doesnt seem to write in to my text file. Can anyone advice me on this? My empty text file name logs is inside src/main/assets folder. Everytime the saveText function is called, it successfully prompt the Toast that shows the string of the saveText, so I wonder why it did not write into the logs textfile.

```
public void saveText(){
    int seconds;
    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    String saveText;
    long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mChronometer.getBase();
    seconds = (int) (elapsedMillis / 1000);
    try {
        outputStream = openFileOutput("logs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        saveText = String.valueOf(seconds);
        outputStream.write(saveText.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, saveText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (Throwable t){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".GameActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".EndActivity" />
</application>
```

Comment: isn't your context null?

Comment: so what shld i put my context as??

Comment: context = getApplicationContext(); 

What does the exception in your toast say?

Comment: it successfully prompt your content is saved to your file, but when i check the text file, there is nothing there

Answer (score 0):

Try setting 
    context = getApplicationContext();
if you are in an activity.

Comment: I tried, but nothing is still being written in the logs file. The string was supposed to be a number and I tried displaying it with toast and there is nothing wrong

Comment: have you tried to save a "normal" String, e.g. saveText = "test"; ?

Comment: i declare saveText = "test" but there is still nothing on the text file